# Spring Webflux - initial message without subscriber

Tags: spring-webflux

I am trying to make an SSE Spring application, using Webflux. According to the documentation, the message is not sent to the sink if there is no subscriber. In my use case, I would like that the subscriber would receive the last message when calling for subscription. I have found that Sink can be configured in following way:

```
Sinks.many().replay().latest();
```

And when I have both publisher and subscriber, and the next subscriber calls for subscription, he receives the last sent message, which is great. However if I don't have any subscribers, publisher sends the message and then first subscriber comes in, it receives none. Which is just as documentation above says actually, but I am thinking how to solve that issue to meet my needs. As a workaround I did something like this:

```
if (shareSinks.currentSubscriberCount() == 0) {
  shareSinks.asFlux().subscribe();
}
shareSinks.tryEmitNext(shareDTO);
```

But subscribing the publisher to its own subscription doesn't sound like a clean way to do this...

Comment: your service should subscribe to your publisher, so that when something gets published, you pass it on to your replay sink. Then someone subscribes to your replay sink they will get what was last passed to the replay sink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of hot and cold publishers. Currently, your publisher (`Sinks.many().replay().latest()`) is a cold publisher. Events that are being emitted while there is no subscriber, will just vanish.

What you need is a so called hot publisher. Hot publishers cache the events and a new subscriber will receive all previously cached events.

This will do the trick:

```java
        final Sinks.Many<String> shareSinks = Sinks.many()
                .replay()
                .all(); // or .limit(10); to keep only the last 10 emissions

        final Flux<String> hotPublisher = shareSinks.asFlux()
                .cache(); // .cache() turns the cold flux into a 
                          // hot flux

        shareSinks.tryEmitNext("1");
        shareSinks.tryEmitNext("2");
        shareSinks.tryEmitNext("3");
        shareSinks.tryEmitNext("4");
        hotPublisher.subscribe(message -> System.out.println("received: " + message));
```

The console print out would be:

```
received: 1
received: 2
received: 3
received: 4
```

The Reactor docu also has a chapter on [hot vs. cold](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold).